# Is it correct to use a 9V 1A transformer to power my project?

Tags: arduino-nano, current

I have a quick question:

I have a small alarm project running on an ArduinoNanoV3 (a chinese clon). Counting *sensors, actuators* and the *arduino itself* the consumed current (theoretically speaking, calculated by the data provided by the datasheets) doesn't approach to a max of 300mA. Now, the way I plan to feed the project is using a 110V (AC) transformer that gives me **9V** output with **1A** maximum output. My fear is the output of this transformer (that says 1A) when in all places recommend not to use sources that give currents greater than **500mA** when you are going to feed it by the pin VIn with **9V**.

My question is: if my project is not going to consume more than 300mA, is there any danger/trouble when connecting the 9V ~ 1A transformer for energize my Arduino based project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> in all places recommend not to use sources that give currents greater than 500mA when you are going to feed it by the pin VIn with 9V.

Nowhere says that.  They say you should not *draw* more than 500mA when you supply with 9V.

The heat generated by the 5V voltage regulator is proportional to the current multiplied by the voltage.  The more current you draw the hotter the regulator will get. The higher the input voltage, the more voltage it has to drop, and thus the hotter it gets.

So the higher the input voltage the lower the current drawn by your project can be before the regulator gets too hot.

Since you are only around 300mA that's below the recommended maximum for a 9V input.